# Jquery sortable - Start sort only with child element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i want to start the sort only when i drag the the icon (`class="icon"`).

**JS**

```
  $('#sortable_test2').sortable({ cancel: '.noDrag' }); // did not work
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sortable_test2" style="margin:20px; background-color:#cacaca;" class="noDrag"> 
  <div id="ct1" class="ct"><div class="icon">icon</div>sortable 1</div>
  <div id="ct2"  class="ct"><div class="icon">icon</div>sortable 2</div>
  <div id="ct3" class="ct"><div class="icon">icon</div>sortable 3</div>
</div>
```

**example**
http://jsbin.com/igohod/15/edit#source

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [handle](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-handle) option:

```
$('#sortable_test2').sortable({ handle: '.icon' });
```

Comment: ups ... Thanks for the fast answer!